# Get Categories from SonataClassificationBundle as Dropdown in SonataBlockBundle block

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am tryin to get a dropdown of all categories I mange in `SonataClassificationBundle` in a custom `SonataBlockBundle` block.

Right now I am building the category tree myself in my block class. This is not correct. But I don't know how to configure my form to make this work automatically.

The code I use right now:

```
    $categories = $this->categoryManager->getCategories('default');

    if (!function_exists('buildCategoryTreeRecursive'))
    {
        function buildCategoryTreeRecursive ($categories, $buffer = null, $level = 0)
        {
            if ($buffer == null)
            {
                $buffer = array();
            }

            foreach ($categories as $category)
            {
                $buffer[$category->getId()] = str_repeat('-', $level).($level > 0 ? ' ' : '').$category->getName();

                $children = $category->getChildren();

                $buffer = buildCategoryTreeRecursive ($children, $buffer, $level + 1);
            }

            return $buffer;
        }
    }

    $categoryTree = buildCategoryTreeRecursive($categories);

    $formMapper->add('settings', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
        'keys' => array(
            array('title',    'text',    array('required' => true)),
            array('subtitle', 'text',    array('required' => false)),
            array('category',  'choice', array('required' => true, 'choices' => $categoryTree)),
        )
    ));
}
```

The code I would expect:

```
    $formMapper->add('settings', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
        'keys' => array(
            array('title',    'text',    array('required' => true)),
            array('subtitle', 'text',    array('required' => false)),
            array('category'),
        )
    ));
```

The category is defined like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

And this works (a dropdown is generated) when I use it in a `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin` subclass:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->with('content')
        ->add('category')
        ->end()
    ;
}
```